# What is the problem to generate routes by user role in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I've started to work on another project 2 days ago and today I see this code in our `routes/api.php`:

```
if ($user->hasRole(‘admin’)) {
  Route::get(‘/orders’, ‘Admin\OrderController@index’);
} 

if ($user->hasRole(‘courier’)) {
  Route::get(‘/orders’, ‘Courier\OrderController@index’);
}

if ($user->hasRole(‘client’)) {
  Route::get(‘/orders’, ‘Client\OrderController@index’);
}
```

I understand that it is probably bad implementation of condition routing, but what are pros and cons of this approach?

Answer (score 1):

A big Con will be that you have an OrderController for three different type of roles.. Which means, that if you ever needs to make a change (which is also legit in an other controller), you would have to change code within three classes.

What if there comes another Role which can place orders? With this approach you would need to create another new Controller file.

A good practice would to have one OrderController.. which will handle **all** Order logic.. **within** this controller you could check the role via

`auth()->user()->hasRole($role)` , and based on this logic you can handle different logic.